# VBA problem with object in get date from pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to get data from a pivot table using the getdate pivot function. However, I get "Application - definied or object - definied error" . I want to take "Suma końcowa" and paste it in the E20 field.

```
Dim ptAs PivotTable
Set pt = wbMe.Sheets("RES_MAT").PivotTables("Tabela przestawna")
wbMe.Sheets("RES_MAT").Range("E20") = pt.GetPivotData("Suma z WYCENA_PLN", "Suma końcowa").Value
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just specify the name of the field, that should return the total,,,

```
Range("E20")=pt.GetPivotData("Etykiety wierszy")
```

Comment: Hi , but i still have same error . :(

Comment: It sounds like "pt" isn't being properly defined.  Check that wbMe is being defined at some point, check that the sheet name is actually RES_MAT and that the pivot table is named "Tabela przestawna".

Comment: right, i changed pivot table name now its working